# NonNullableFieldWasNullError when trying to use analysis under graphql-java

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I am fairly new to graphql and couldn't find an answer to the error given below even though I searched, any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to use the MaxQueryComplexityInstrumentation to calculate the complexity of a given query. Here the backend I used was a mock backend (https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/swapi).

The code given below works fine for a local graphql server, but won't work with the mock backend. One difference that I've noticed is when the required symbol ("!") is given for that particular query within the schema this seems to be happening.

After trying the code with a debugger, I found out that this error is caused by the ".execute()" call. Also, note that the mock backend returns values and does not give any null values as responses.

This is the code written to set up the MaxQueryComplexityInstrumentation.

```
    private boolean queryComplexityAnalysis(String payload) {
        GraphQL runtime = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema)
                .instrumentation(new MaxQueryComplexityInstrumentation(GraphQLAPISecurityConstants.MAX_QUERY_COMPLEXITY))
                .build();

        try {
            ExecutionResult execution = runtime.execute(payload);
            List<GraphQLError> errors = execution.getErrors();
            if (errors.size()>0) {
                for(GraphQLError temp : errors) {
                    log.error(temp);
                }
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("Maximum query complexity was not exceeded");
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

If MAX_QUERY_COMPLEXITY = 3, and I pass in a query with complexity 7, it gives the correct response saying that the maximum query complexity exceeded.

```
graphql.execution.AbortExecutionException: maximum query complexity exceeded 7 > 3
```

But if I pass in a query with anything less than or equal to 3 (for example, "{ allFilms{title  episodeId}}"), it gives a NonNullableFieldWasNullError as shown below. Although the expected result here is to just print "Maximum query complexity was not exceeded".

```
NonNullableFieldWasNullError{message='Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'null' within parent 'Query' (/allFilms)', path=[allFilms]}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!